# Transferring source code from one pc to another

Tags: java, netbeans

My development PC was having hardware problems, so I copied my source program code (Netbeans java) and loaded it into a backup laptop. When my desktop pc failed, I went to my backup laptop, to recreate my project. Everything worked basically except the source code I copied did not have some library modules as well as some other unknown modules. I got one program to work by loading the required library module in Netbeans, however one of the other programs is failing with the following error:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\aaageing.txt (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at my.TTjav.TTjavAgeing.main(TTjavAgeing.java:34)

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.<init>(Writer.java:88)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:109)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:148)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:131)
    at my.TTjav.TTjavAgeing.main(TTjavAgeing.java:38)
```

and I'm not sure which library modules or?? I need.

I am using the following:

```
File outFile = new File("C:\\aaageing.txt");
FileOutputStream outFileStream = null;
        try {
            outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TTjavAgeing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,        null, ex);
        }
PrintWriter  outStream = new PrintWriter(outFileStream);
```

Comment: You seem to be having an exception during runtime... And the exception clearly states **Access is denied** to the file. There's not library modules missing or anything...

Comment: it seems like you are not allowed to write to the "C:\"-root directory on your laptop... Try running your programm as administrator and see if it succeeds in this case...

Comment: Looks like an issue with writing to the root of the C: drive. Simply move that file to a subfolder of the C: drive and change your code to point to the new location instead.

Answer (score 2):

As you are getting "`Access is denied`", then you need to give permission.

### To change ownership,

1. Right-click on file `aaageing.txt` in C drive,
2. Then select `Properties`, and go to `Security tab`.
3. Now click the `Advanced button`(shown in the link).
4. Next, you need to go to Owner tab and hit the `Edit` button.
5. Then in the new dialog window choose the new owner and then click
   OK.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/

After that it will run smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

check the file `C:\aaageing.txt`
if exists run like administrator or change permission of the file

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace is telling you everything you are asking about.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\aaageing.txt (Access is denied)

It seems like you do not have required access rights to get to that file. Try running as an administrator.